# KDTree counts during matplotlib.animation

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, kdtree, particles

I am trying to find the best way to use `KDTree.query_ball_point` function to find the concentration of particles within 'r' distance, for every particle at each step of the animation, and have the number value from this count used in the `conc` equation. Essentially I am trying to make the settling (stokes) velocity a function of the concentration of surrounding particles.

So far my attempts have not worked, below is the code I am working with (excluding my failed KDTree attempts)

UPDATE: I have added in the def "concentration" to evaluate the concentration of nearest neighboring particles at every step of the animation. Additionally, I have changed the "r" (radius) to be constant so there is no variation in the size of particles so that the effects of the concentration of neighboring particles on the particle settling velocity can be observed more clearly (currently not working at all).

**The problem: I can't figure out what is wrong with `def concentration`. there seems to be a bug, as the animation will not run.**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random
import pdb
from scipy import spatial
from scipy.spatial import KDTree

n=5
sigma=0.01


#m = np.random.uniform(n)

pp = 2.56 # pp = particle density (Sphene=3.53) (Feldspar=2.56) 
#(g/cm^3)

pf = 2.7 # pf = fluid density(g/cm^3)

g = 9.8 # g = gravity (m/s^2)

r = 0.003 # r = radius of sphere (meter)

mu = 0.53 # mu = dynamic viscosity of fluid (log10Poise)

rp = 0.0005 #radius around particle to check for nearest neighbor

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
az = plt.axes(xlim=(-1, 1), ylim=(-100, 0))
xdata, ydata = [0.0], [0.0]
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro', animated=True)

#pdb.set_trace()
def v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu):
    top=2*(pp-pf)*g*(r**2)
    bottom=9*mu
    ws=top/bottom
    return ws

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(  -2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 0)
    return ln,

def concentration(xdata, ydata, rp):
    pdb.set_trace()
    coords = list(zip(xdata, ydata))
    tree = spatial.KDTree(coords)
    test = np.column_stack([xdata, ydata])
    nnl = tree.query_ball_point(test, rp) #nearest neighbors as a list 
                    #(had tree in here before test but shape was wrong)
    nnt = np.zeros(len(nnl)) #nearest neighbors total
    for i in range(len(nnt)): 
        nnt[i] = len(nnl[i])
    return nnt,

def update(frame):
    global xdata
    global ydata
    global rp
    global concentration
    xdata = xdata + np.random.normal(0, sigma, n)
    #ydata = ydata + np.random.normal(-0.1, sigma, n)
    wss = v_stokes(pp,pf,g,r,mu)
    if frame == 0.0:
        ydata = np.zeros(len(xdata)) #makes the ydata length = xdata at 
                                     #time 0
    cp = concentration(xdata, ydata, rp)
    ydata = ydata + (wss*(1-cp))
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                init_func=init, blit=True, interval=50)
plt.show()
```

**Below is the code that I started with, basic animation of particles.**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import *
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import random

n=100
sigma=0.1
nt=2000

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xdata, ydata = [0.0], [0.0]
ln, = plt.plot([], [], 'ro', animated=True)

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(  -5, 5)
    ax.set_ylim(-10, 0)
    return ln,

def update(frame):
    global xdata
    global ydata
    xdata = xdata + np.random.normal(0, sigma, n)
    ydata = ydata + np.random.normal(-0.1, sigma, n)
    ln.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return ln,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 128),
                    init_func=init, blit=True, in)
plt.show()
```

Comment: If you exclude the part that you want to get help with, people will just see some working code and will not know where the problem lies.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest see updated code, It runs but I don't think the for loop is working correctly. Points with no other points around them should be settling faster than the points surrounded by many points.

Comment: The problem is not at all clear. What's wrong with the animation? Is this a physics problem or a programming issue?